How to handle my company keeping me in a position I'm asking to step down from until they find a replacement?
I recently asked to voluntary demote my self due to mental health concerns. I told them in my demotion letter that I'd work through the schedules that were already posted so they wouldn't have to remake schedules. They told me I can't step down until they hire my replacement.
Can they really force me to continue in this position until they find a replacement, given that could be more than 6 months before they find my replacement. Is there anything I can do about this?

Please add location

Questions starting with (or, containing) "Is it legal..." are best suited for [law.se].

Depending on the laws in your country, you may be able to force the company to meet your needs by getting a letter from your doctor.

"You say I can't step down until you hire my replacement?  That's too bad, I liked working here. If I have to quit, I guess I can do that but I'd rather stay."

@SouravGhosh No, they are not, please stop that. This is perfectly in scope for this site, since it is something any trained HR person should know. And law.se will just close it on arrival, because they do not do personalized advice. This is not helping.

I will reopen this question since it is on-topic here, this is simple labor law that any trained professional in that area should know. However, without a juristiction (country and/or federal state) it is pointless to discuss here. If you add a tag to your post with your country, I will reopen it.

Can they force you? That depends on your employment contract and laws governing your location. In many places, you can leave right away.

Is there actually a vacant position you can step down into?

Note that they don't have to accept your stepping down. They could say that since you are not fulfilling the responsibilities of your current role, you're simply fired. If you would rather they work with you to keep you in the company, you have to work with them to make sure their needs are met.
You may be able to speed this up by offering to actively train someone to handle the responsibilities you are relinquishing. Depending on what they are and who is available, this might let them replace you with someone already present. Assuming, of course, that you can help them find someone else who is ready to take on this position... with the caveat that since you don't feel ready, your judgment may be suspect.
They have work that needs to be done. They need someone to do it. Until they have someone else to do it, you are it.
Your other alternative, of course  is to simply quit entirely and look for employment elsewhere, if you don't like what you're being offered. But until you do, your responsibilities are as management shall reasonably direct.

"you're simply fired". It's actually worse than that, in many jurisdictions you wouldn't be considered fired, you'd have been considered to have resigned. So you may miss out on benefits that you may be otherwise entitled to.

This is correct if one assumes for example US jurisdiction. If on the other hand, OP is for example somewhere in the EU and has some doctor backing up their mental health concerns, the situation would be very different and OP could essentially expect the company to cater to their needs immediately, regardless of any replacements.

@quarague: With the doctor backing it up, sure. But how the company cares to those needs might still be an open question. It might be allowing them some leave time to recover, or it might be getting them more education so they are better able to handle this task, or any of several other possible solutions. One would hope, even in the us, that accompany would recognize that if somebody has been promoted beyond their competence the right thing to do is to put them back in the previous position. But how quickly that can be done needs to be determined, and unfortunately not every company does so.


I recently asked to voluntary demote my self

Note that you cannot self-demote. All you did here is to ask your employer to change the scope of your assignments. The decision is not yours.

They told me I can t step down until they hire my replacement is this legal?

Legal questions are highly location dependent but in most legislations this would entirely legal: the company can chose to accept your request or not. The only exception would be if a medical professional certifies that you are currently not capabale of executing your duties as assigned and that specific accommodation is needed.

Can they really force me to continue in this position until they find a replacement.

Of course not. They cannot force you do to anything: you can always resign and look elsewhere.
Again what happened here is that you simply asked for a different assignment. The company can choose to accept or not. You choose to do what they ask you to or not.
If you want to keep working for the company, your best bet is to negotiate in good faith. The company values what you are doing: otherwise the wouldn't push that hard. That also means, they do NOT want you to walk out tomorrow morning, so you have a bit of leverage.
Propose a time-bounded transition plan. Start with a month and see if you can get them to agree. Maybe there is another person in the team that could be an "acting" role until a full time replacement has been found. You could coach and mentor that person without having to deal with they day to day yourself.

I'm sorry to hear you're dealing with this challenging situation. Prioritizing your mental health is crucial, and it's commendable that you've taken steps to address it.
First, ensure that your initial request clearly highlights your mental health concerns and includes any supporting medical documentation. Emphasize the urgency and the impact that continuing in your current role is having on your well-being.
Next, have an open and honest conversation with your HR department. Explain your situation in detail and discuss the importance of addressing this issue promptly for your overall health. Propose temporary solutions while they search for a replacement, such as reduced hours, shifting some of your more demanding tasks to other team members, or hiring temporary support.
It's important to research your rights regarding workplace accommodations for mental health. In many regions, mental health issues are covered under workplace disability laws, and employers are required to make reasonable accommodations. Consulting a legal advisor or a labor rights organization can help you understand your protections better.
Additionally, discuss the possibility of an internal transfer to a less demanding role as a temporary measure until they find a permanent replacement. If conversations don't yield results, consider formalizing your request in writing. A detailed letter addressing your concerns, the impact on your health, and the urgency can sometimes prompt quicker action.
Your mental health is paramount. Advocate for yourself and seek support from HR, legal advisors, and mental health professionals to find a solution that works for both you and your employer.

I personally would never talk about my medical requirements with HR, they are not there to protect you, they are there to protect the companies interests

This answer looks to me like it was copy-pasted from some AI tool, and quite likely not even read by the user that posted it. This user looks to have a history of posting AI-generated spam promoting their company (now deleted answer: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/198717) so I would tend to treat this answer the same.

Lets rephrase this question.
I am quitting my current job and want to be rehired by the company I work for to a lower stress position.
Is it legal for the company I work for to require that my current position be filled before they will allow me to quit and be rehired for a lower level position?
The answer is "yes".
Self demoting to a lower level position is basically you quitting your current position and getting rehired to a lower level position. Your current employer is legally allowed to put conditions on you for that to happen.

I don't think there are any jurisdictions where this is true. For example, when calculating seniority, if you quit and restarted your seniority clock (even if just for "years of service" to get more vacation) would restart. But if you're demoted it does not. The employer is allowed to put conditions, sure, but not because what the OP is asking for is the same as quitting.

the company might want the position filled, but you can quit - end of story...

@KateGregory - US Government allows someone to work, say 10 years, and then leave civilian service. If they were to return after say 5 years, they would continue to earn towards their retirement starting at 10 years, and that includes everything that goes with having 10 years as a civilian government servant. USG has hundreds of thousands of employees. What might not be counted is the time outside of the government. However, experience is considered towards a job offer, if it’s deemed relevant. They could leave at Step 5 (9 years) and return to a Step 6 within the same grade (potentially)

@SolarMike this is trueish. But as OP wants to transition to another role inside of the company, not so much no.

@Donald where I work, private sector. seniority etc... sticks with you if you come back within a year of leaving.

@Questor - I can work in one role within an Agency, resign, and then after the period of time come back to an entirely different agency in an entirely different field.
